# Beamerposter not showing correct fonts in math mode

Tags: beamer, fonts, beamerposter

I am making a poster using `beamer` package and I have problems in mathematical symbols like summation and fractions. My preamble file has following

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
 \usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} 
 \usetheme{confposter} 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
```

These equations give me problems

```
\begin{equation}
V(\phi) =  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \left(\sfrac {1}{2} V_m ( 1 - \cos k \phi) \right) 
\end{equation}

 \begin{equation}
 \frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d^2 x} \left( V(\phi) \right) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}     \left(\sfrac {1}{2} V_m^2 ( \cos k \phi) \right)
 \end{equation}
```

For instance I need large summation and small fractions. but I am not getting it right.

What I am actually using is the template given in this link, since I am new to LATEX. 
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster 
You can put this modified equations to this templates to test that. 
If you need my code I can provide but still based on this template.

Comment: Please edit your question to have a complete document so that people can test it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The culprit seems to be in the file `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`, which defines the `confposter` theme. It loads the package `lmodern` which supposedly changes the fonts. I don't know why but commenting out `\RequirePackage{lmodern}` in the `.sty` file seems to give you back the big summation sign. Also, you need to load `\usepackage{xfrac}` in your main document in order to use the `\sfrac` command for small fractions.

Comment: I tried to add \usepackage{xfrac} But now gives problems. texify.exe: Permission denied: main.log texify.exe: Data: main.log

Comment: I can't even run anything in Mictex. Please tell me how to recover

Comment: do you know where to find this log file

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the `exscale` package after `lmodern` has been read in.  This is a common problem when needing these fonts at large sizes, see the discussion on the TeX FAQ at https://texfaq.org/FAQ-exscale.

Incidentally your code snippet is missing the `xfrac` package for the `\sfrac` command.  However, as egreg correctly says this looks bad and is ambiguous.  Perhaps you mean `\tfrac` instead - this is what I have now used.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} 
\usetheme{confposter}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size

\title{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} % Poster title

\author{John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith} % Author(s)

\institute{Department and University Name} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{equation}
        V(\phi) =  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \left(\tfrac {1}{2} V_m ( 1 -
          \cos k \phi) \right)  
      \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
    \frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d^2 x} \left( V(\phi) \right) =
    \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \left(\tfrac {1}{2} V_m^2 ( \cos k \phi)
    \right) 
  \end{equation} 
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\xfrac` is completely inappropriate: the result is ambiguous, besides being awful.

Comment: @egreg Agreed - just that the poster's code contained the `\sfrac` command, so loading the package was necessary to make it compile...

Comment: @egreg I have now put `\tfrac` there instead.